# How to append rows to Gtk.ListStore?

Tags: python, pygtk, gtk3, pygobject

im trying to switch my application from python2.7 pyGTK to Python3 and pyGObject and having hard time with appending rows to my Gtk.ListStore :/

This code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from gi.repository import Gtk

listStore = Gtk.ListStore(str)
itr = Gtk.TreeIter()
listStore.append(itr)
listStore.set_value(itr, 0, 'Its working')
```

gives me always error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 7, in <module>
    listStore.append(itr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 1017, in append
    return self._do_insert(-1, row)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 1008, in _do_insert
    row, columns = self._convert_row(row)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 850, in _convert_row
    if len(row) != n_columns:
TypeError: object of type 'TreeIter' has no len()
```

what is going on? How can I append new row into Gtk.ListStore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use the following command:

```
itr = store.append(['Its working', ])
```

You can find more example in [The Python GTK+ 3 Tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/treeview.html#the-model).